# Netbeans PHP Go to Declarations serves up functions from across several projects, not limited to just my current project

Tags: php, netbeans, drupal

I work primarily in Drupal/PHP projects. For some reason, once in a while, when setting up a new project my code completion and Go to Declaration serves up results from other projects outside my Sources folder!  Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Lovely. Apparently Global PHP Include Path is pretty big.  Removing it from my Project Properties > Include Path gives narrows the results down to only this project (and its source-tracked Drupal codebase).
[screenshot of Netbeans Project Properties Include Sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX3Ug.jpg)

I don't know what other fallout there may be, but hopefully this helps someone down the line.